# Kentico 9 Culture error on file upload from CMS Desk, in IE

Tags: kentico

I'm in Canada, but the site in EN only, so I haven't set any cultures as it's not needed. I have an editor getting errors when uploading files, either PDFs or word docs.

Browser is IE, and the computer region is set to Canada. On my local machine, i got the same error, set my computer region to US, reboot, same error.

Here's the error for the event log:

> An error occurred when saving data. Please see event log for more details.
>   Message: [TreeNode.InsertInternal]: Document culture 'en-CA' is not allowed on site 'KFFIntranet'.
>
> Exception type: System.Exception
>   Stack Trace: 
>    at CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.InsertInternal(TreeNode parent)
>    at CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.Insert(TreeNode parent, Boolean useDocumentHelper)
>    at CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(TreeNode node, TreeNode parentNode, TreeProvider tree, Boolean allowCheckOut)
>    at CMSModules_Content_CMSDesk_New_NewFile.ProcessDirectUploader() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\New\NewFile.aspx.cs:line 467
>    at CMSModules_Content_CMSDesk_New_NewFile.DocumentManager_OnSaveData(Object sender, DocumentManagerEventArgs e) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Intranet\CMS\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\New\NewFile.aspx.cs:line 310
>    at CMS.FormControls.CMSAbstractManager`2.RaiseSaveData(EventArgsType args)
>    at CMS.FormControls.CMSDocumentManager.SaveDocumentInternal(String actionContext)

Chrome seems to be working fine.

I've doubled check the settings, and there is only the default culture.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things:

- Make sure you have the default content culture and visitor culture set on the site in the Sites app
- In Sites>Site>Cultures make sure you only have English (especially if you're not using any other language)
- In Settings>Content make sure you have the default content culture set to English

The combination of 1 or more of these changes should fix your issue.

Comment: I'm going to double check again. Working fine in Chrome is the odd thing. IE, what ya gonna do :)